# Telling Qmake How To Produce Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, cross-compiling, qmake

I'd like to know if there's any way I could specify to qmake the target architecture I'd like to cross compile to?

Something like:

```
qmake -qt4 -makefile -target_architecture
```

Answer (score 1):

`qmake -spec <spec>` where `<spec>` can be found here: `qt-src/mkspecs/` or here `$$QT_HOME/mkspecs/`.